# Triggering selected element to be first in Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Originally this code was working with Isotope v1, but I upgraded to the latest Isotope to enable packery mode and for some reason I'm getting an error. (Uncaught TypeError: $item.hasClass is not a function)

```
var $container = $('#grid'),
$item = $('.cell');
getSortData : {
      selected : function( $item ){
        // sort by selected first, then by original order
        return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -500 : 0 ) + $item.index();
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'selected'
```

Would it be better to use jQuery .find instead of

```
($item.hasClass('selected') ? -500 : 0) + $item.index();
```

Comment: Above your return inside `getSortData` try `console.log($item);` to make sure `$item` outputs a jQuery collection wrapper in the browser console .

Comment: figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, figure.cell, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]]

Those all are elements which selected could have the selected class. But for some reason the code under getSortData isn't working properly.

Comment: Instead of checking `hasClass()` what about using this `return ($item[0].classList.contains('selected') ? -500 : 0 ) + $item.index();` the `[0]` in `$item[0]` is there so presuming `$item` is a jQuery collection wrapper, it will allow you to use jQuery wrapper selector with vanilla JS. If `$item` is not a jQuery wrapper then `$item` is some other type of object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList .. or try `$item.classList.contains('selected') ? -500 : 0 ) + $item.index();`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: try `$item.classList.contains('selected') ? -500 : 0 ) + $item.index();` if that doesnt work you might have to post issue on https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope